# Is there a way to get the class that shows "$0" element when inspecting HTML?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm a newbie and I'm trying to scrape postcodes from this website "https://www.doogal.co.uk/UKPostcodes.php?Search=AB". Got stuck when trying to create a variable for a td tag that has a class "$0".

I've tried the following:

1. Tried to use CSS Selector
2. Tried using XPath
3. Used shell to check that I was able to get it data on both.

```
def parse(self, response):

    code = UkPostcodeItem()

    sample_codes = response.xpath('//td[@class="$0"]')

    for codes in sample_codes:
       postcodes = codes.xpath('//td/a/text()').extract()

       code['post'] = postcodes

       yield code
```

Using XPath in Scrapy Shell:

```
>>> response.xpath("//td/a/text()").extract()
['AB1 0AA', 'AB1 0AB', 'AB1 0AD', 'AB1 0AE', 'AB1 0AF', 'AB1 0AG', 'AB1 0AJ', 'AB1 0AL', 'AB1 0AN', 'AB1 0AP', 'AB1 0AQ', 'AB1 0AR', 'AB1 0AS', 'AB1 0AT', 'AB1 0AX', 'AB1 0BA', 'AB1 0BB', 'AB1 0BD', 'AB1 0BE', 'AB1 0BJ', 'AB1 0BL', 'AB1 0BN', 'AB1 0BP', 'AB1 0BQ', 'AB1 0BR', 'AB1 0BS', 'AB1 0BT', 'AB1 0BX',
```

Using CSS Selector in Scrapy Shell:

```
>>> response.css('td a::text').extract()
['AB1 0AA', 'AB1 0AB', 'AB1 0AD', 'AB1 0AE', 'AB1 0AF', 'AB1 0AG', 'AB1 0AJ', 'AB1 0AL', 'AB1 0AN', 'AB1 0AP', 'AB1 0AQ', 'AB1 0AR', 'AB1 0AS', 'AB1 0AT', 'AB1 0AX', 'AB1 0BA', 'AB1 0BB', 'AB1 0BD', 'AB1 0BE', 'AB1 0BJ', 'AB1 0BL', 'AB1 0BN', 'AB1 0BP', 'AB1 0BQ', 'AB1 0BR', 'AB1 0BS', 'AB1 0BT', 'AB1 0BX'
```

Comment: I don't see `class="$0"` anywhere in that website.

Comment: it seems responsive in a way that when you inspect it and hover it it turn the class "hover".

Comment: That's a variable in the browser console, it's not part of the webpage. When you select an element, it sets the variable `$0` to the element, so you can refer to it in the console.

Comment: Yes, that `$0` is just the mercy from Chrome. Which let the poor frontend developers feel a little bit comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`//tr[@class='hover']/td[1]/a`
Though I'm confused, what's the difference in your post codes vs sample codes? What are you trying to do? Just use the xpaths you used in shell that are working

Comment: The difference between the post_codes and sample_codes is that the post_codes is the variable for iterated text scraped while the sample_code is where you point the parser where it can find the td a. I based it on a tutorial that I saw about scrapy.

Comment: I see you posted an answer. Do you use that variable somewhere else?

Comment: just used in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem with the help of my coworker, who works in QA automation. He was able to help me identify on what was needed. 
Instead this:

sample_codes = response.xpath('//td[@class="$0"]')

I was able to solve it by using a CSS Selector and with this by this code:

sample_codes = response.css('table.postalcodes')

if it was xpath:

sample_codes = response.xpath('//table[@postalcodes]')

So by pointing where the td is from, it was able to create a variable it.